# Are type-erased Any... structs necessary for non-generic protocols?

Tags: swift

When defining a generic Swift protocol (that is, a protocol with at least one `associatedtype`) for a framework, it's common practice to also provide an `Any...` struct, e.g. `SomethingType` and `AnySomething`. For example, the standard library does this with `AnySequence`.

Is this necessary for a non-generic protocol? In that case, you can refer to the protocol type directly, so it seems that the protocol itself is already a type-erased version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A protocol that does not have an associated type can easily be used as a Type in its own right.  This is often done to allow diverse concrete types to be stored in collections identifying them only by a common protocol that all the concrete types implement.

Or to put it another way "type erasing" is a technique for dealing with protocols that have associated types.  If your protocol does not have associated types, there is no need to employ the technique.